# Conditional checking on Atomic Integer thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

Sample code

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AtomicIntegerSample {

private final AtomicInteger successFullSyncCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
private final AtomicLong overallSyncTimeTaken  = new AtomicLong(0);

public void incrementSuccessFullSyncCount() {
    this.successFullSyncCount.incrementAndGet();
}


public void addOverallSyncTimeTaken(final Long syncTimeTaken) {
    overallSyncTimeTaken.addAndGet(syncTimeTaken);
}
/**
 * Can be called by multiple threads
 * @return
 */
public long getAverageSuccessfulSyncTimeTaken() {
    if (successFullSyncCount.get() == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return overallSyncTimeTaken.get() / successFullSyncCount.get();
    }
}
```

In method `getAverageSuccessfulSyncTimeTaken()` there is conditional check to avoid arithmetic exception.

The class ApplicationScoped, and this method can be called by multiple threads concurrently.

Is the method thread safe?. If I replace the code as follows, is it thread safe?

```
 /**
 * Can be called by multiple threads
 * @return
 */
public long getAverageSuccessfulSyncTimeTaken() {
       return overallSyncTimeTaken.get() / successFullSyncCount.get();

}
```

Then arithmetic exception will be thrown. How to optimally synchronize this code?. I mean only if successFullSyncCount.get() == 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't throw any exception, but it could return incorrect results:

- the time and the count are incremented separately. They're not incremented both at once, in a single atomic operation
- the time and the count are read separately, instead of being read both at once in a single atomic operation.

So, you could very well read a time of 100 in a thread, then have another thread increment the count a few times, then read the count and perform the division. That can thus lead to an average time per sync that is lower than it is in reality. It could be a good enough approximation, or not.

Comment: Agreed, the method getAverageSuccessfulSyncTimeTaken() is not thread safe: it will not cause any Exceptions but might return unexpected results. Isn't it also true that the AtomicInteger could be updated during the if/else statement itself and thus successFullSyncCount.get() can return different results in the if and else statements?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, but if the count can only increase (which seems to be the case), the exception will be avoided. That's the only purpose of the `if`

Comment: If I replace the code overallSyncTimeTaken.get() / successFullSyncCount.get();  Is the method synchronized. Is there any way to synchronize this method?. I mean , I wanted to synchronize this code only first time if successFullSyncCount.get() is zero

Answer (score 0):

Below is a version that does not use atomic objects.

If you expect times and counts to be updated together, a synchronized block might be a better fit. This will prevent your average method from being off by more than one. Admittedly a synchronized block is slower that the native atomic implementations, but I'm not sure optimization wouldn't be premature.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AtomicIntegerSample {

private int successFullSyncCount = 0;
private long overallSyncTimeTaken  = 0;


synchronized public void addSyncTimeTakenAndIncrementSyncCount(final Long syncTimeTaken) {
    overallSyncTimeTaken+=syncTimeTaken;
    successFullSyncCount++;
}
/**
 * Can be called by multiple threads
 * @return
 */
public long getAverageSuccessfulSyncTimeTaken() {
    if (successFullSyncCount.get() == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return overallSyncTimeTaken.get() / (float) successFullSyncCount.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to reimplement the getAverageSuccessfulSyncTimeTaken method.